# Java File "Top" Parent

Tags: java, file, scala

I've got a java.io.File, e.g

```
/foo/bar/baz
```

I'd like to get the "top" parent of the file, in this case

```
/foo/
```

Obviously, this is Linux specific - I'm not bothered about a solution being cross-platform compatible, but if it is it's more elegant!

The best I've managed to come up with, in Scala, is the following:

```
def topParent( file : File ) : File =
{
    var temp = file
    while ( temp.getParent != "/" ) temp = temp.getParentFile
    temp
}
```

Which has the following behaviour:

```
scala> topParent( new java.io.File( "/foo/bar/baz" ) )
res14: java.io.File = /foo
```

but it seems a little inelegant. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Will this work if the file were `../../foo/bar/baz`?

Comment: No. I'll make sure it's an absolute path I'm passing in - that's a good point. This is why I'm wondering if there's a better solution!

Comment: You could probably make it look nicer with recursion and `match` but it would essentially be the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a recursive solution that does the same thing in functional style with tail recursion, as bmorris591 pointed out in the comment:

```
@tailrec def topParent(file: File): File = 
    if(file.getParent == "/") file else topParent(file.getParentFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `getCanonicalFile` to make sure it's in proper form.

I'm not sure what you think is more elegant; you'll have to walk your way all the way back anyway.  You could also do something like

```
def topParent(file: File): Option[File] = {
  Iterator.iterate(file.getCanonicalFile)(_.getParentFile).
    takeWhile(_ != null).
    toList.
    reverse.
    drop(1).
    headOption
}
```

which at least avoids getting the parent twice.